# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^{\ln(n)}}=\infty$

Tags: limits

Could anyone please give a **hint** for showing the following? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^{\ln(n)}}=\infty$$

Comment: $\log \frac{a}{b} = \log a - \log b$

Answer (score 5):

**HINTS**: 
$$\lim\exp(\ldots)=\exp(\lim\ldots)$$
$$\dfrac{2^n}{n^{\ln{n}}}=\exp\left(n\ln{2}-\ln^2{n}\right)$$

Comment: @ Demosthene: Why is it true that $\lim\exp(\ldots)=\exp(\lim\ldots)$?

Comment: @CKKOY Because $\exp(x)$ is continuous. This is basically a way of saying that we first evaluate the limit of the argument, then exponentiate it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Taking the logarithm you have
$$\lim_n \log(2^n)-\log(n^{\log n}) = \lim_n (\log 2)n-\log^{2}n = \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

A fancy way: put

$$a_n=\frac{n^{\log n}}{2^n}\implies \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{n^{\log n/n}}2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12<1$$

Thus, the series $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;$ converges, so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}=\infty$$

Comment: Should the second equality read $\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{n^{\log n^{\frac{1}{n}}}}2$?

Comment: @CKKOY No: $$\sqrt[n] a=a^{1/n}\implies \sqrt[n]{n^{\log n}}=\left(n^{\log n}\right)^{1/n}=n^{\frac1n\log n}=n^{\log n/n}$$ Of course, **if you meant** $\;n^{\log \left(n^{1/n}\right)}\;$ then yes, as $\;\log x^a=a\log x\;$

Comment: Ah - I think that I misread your notation.  By $n^{\log n/n}$, do you mean the same as $n^{(\log n)/n}$?

Comment: Yes, I did mean $n^{\log(n^{1/n})}$.

Comment: @CKKOY Yes, of course. Most more or less veteran members of this site are very clear with their notations...unless some mistake or typing error slips in.

Comment: Why does it follow that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges?

Comment: The first part shows that the $\;n$-th root of the general temrm tends to something less than one. By this testm the poisitive infinite sereis $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges.

Comment: Which 'test' are you referring to, please?

Comment: The $\;n$-th root test or root test...google it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would observe that showing that $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{ln(n+1)}}{n^{ln(n)}} < 2$ is an equivalent proof.

And to do that, rather than using logarithm's algebraic properties, I would use the fact that it increases very slowly, for example:

$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{ln(n+1)}}{n^{ln(n)}} < lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{ln(n+1)}}{n^{ln(n+1)}} = lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{ln(n+1)}$

And now, for $n > 3$  we have: $ln(n+1) < n/2$.

We're almost done now, can you see why?

Comment: I don't yet see how you arrived at the first sentence of your answer.

Comment: Be $a$ the growing factor for $n \to \infty$ to the formula in my first sentence. If we show that $a < 2 $ then the growing factor of our original limit is $2/a > 1$ and therefore diverges like geometric series do.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^{\ln n}}=\infty\;.$$

For any $M\!>\!0$ there exists $k_M\!\!=\!\max\!\left\{\left(1\!+\!\lfloor\ln\!M\rfloor\right)^{\,2}\!,34^2\right\}\!\!\in\!\Bbb N\,$ such that for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;\land\;n>k_M\;$ it results that

$\dfrac{2^n}{n^{\ln n}}=\dfrac{e^{n\ln2}}{e^{\ln^2\!n}}=e^{n\ln2-\ln^2\!n}>e^{\frac12n-16\ln^2\left(\sqrt[4]n\right)}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{ because }\,0\leqslant\ln x<x}\\\text{ for all }x\in[1,\infty[\,.}{>}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!e^{\frac12n-16\sqrt n}=$

$=e^{\frac12\sqrt n\left(\sqrt n-32\right)}>e^{\sqrt n}>e^{\left|1+\lfloor\ln M\rfloor\right|}\geqslant e^{1+\lfloor\ln M\rfloor}>e^{\ln M}=M\,.$

By definition of limit, it follows that $\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^n}{n^{\ln n}}=\infty\,.$

Comment: Nice alternative (+1). As already noticed all boils down in $e^n \ge n^a \implies e^{\sqrt n} \ge n \implies log n\le \sqrt n \implies \log^2 n\le n$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, not so much effective in this case, by ratio test

$$\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{\ln(n+1)}}}{\frac{2^n}{n^{\ln(n)}}}=2\frac{n^{\ln(n)}}{(n+1)^{\ln(n+1)}}=2\frac{n^{\ln(n)}}{(n+1)^{\ln(n)}}\frac{(n+1)^{\ln(n)}}{(n+1)^{\ln(n+1)}}=2\frac{(n+1)^{\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)}}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{\log n}}\to 2$$

indeed $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{\log n}=e^{\log n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}\le e^{\frac{\log n}n}\to e^0=1$.

Comment: Good answer. I like it (+1).