# Is the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log (n))^{\log (\log (n))}}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log (n))^{\log (\log (n))}}$$

convergent?

I know that $ \log(\log n) >2$.  Now $\log(\log(\log (n))) >  \log 2$.  After that  I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321738/does-sum-n-3-infty-frac-1-log-n-log-logn-converge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since $x\ge \log^2(x)$ for $x\ge \log(2)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_2^L \frac{1}{(\log(x))^{\log(\log(x))}}\,dx&\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto e^x}\int_{\log(2)}^{\log(L)}\frac{e^x}{x^{\log(x)}}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{\log(2)}^{\log(L)}e^{x-\log^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&\ge \log(L/2)
\end{align}$$

Hence, the integral test guarantees that the series of interest diverges.

Comment: I can't manage series by integrals abd I can't follow but it seems a nice proof!

Comment: @gimusi See [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) on the integral test.  It is effectively the same as the Cauchy Condensation test.   And a simple proof of the latter is based on the former.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $a^b$ $= (e^{\log a})^b$ $= e^{b\log a}$.  Applying this to your denominator turns it into $e^{(\log\log n)^2}$, and now you should be able to compare with $e^{\log n}$...

Comment: (+1) I don't know why this hasn't received many more up votes.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let use the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$ 0 \ \leq\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)\ \leq\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}f(2^{n})\ \leq\ 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$$

that is

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log\log n}} \ge \frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(\log 2^n)^{\log\log 2^n}}=\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(n\log 2)^{\log (n\log 2)}}$$

Comment: im not getting @gimusi...is there  is  any simple  method is there...?

Comment: @Stupid that's not so bad!

Comment: Why dont you finish the question ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus it's just an hint and the last series seems seriously aimed to diverge

Comment: @Stupid To finish note that $$\frac{2^n}{(n\log 2)^{\log (n\log 2)}}\ge\frac{2^n}{n^{\log (n)}}$$

Comment: @user, $$\;\dfrac{2^n}{n^{\log(n)}}=\dfrac{e^{n\log(2)}}{e^{\log^2(n)}}=e^{n\log(2)-\log^2(n)}>e^{\frac12n-16\log^2(\sqrt[4]n)}> e^{\frac12n-16\sqrt n}=e^{\frac12\sqrt n\left(\sqrt n-32\right)}>e^{\sqrt n}\;$$ for any $\;n>34^2=1156\,.\,$ Is there a quicker way to get a divergent series whose terms are smaller than the original series ?

Comment: @Angelo We can also use root test $\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{2^n}{n^{\log(n)}}} \to 2$ or from here $e^{n\log 2 -\log^2 n )}= e^{n\left(\log 2-\frac{\log^2 n}{n}\right)}$, in both cases using that $\frac{\log^2 n}{n} \to 0$.

Comment: @user, I know we can use root test or calculate a limit, but I ask you if there is a quicker way to get a divergent series whose terms are smaller than the original series (by using only inequalities).

Comment: @Angelo isn’t this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729853 good enough?

Comment: @user, yes, of course it is a very good answer, but I want to know how to get, in a quick way, a divergent series smaller than the original one without using integral test or root test, etc, but using only inequalities.

Comment: @Angelo Indeed in that solution they are suggesting $$\frac{1}{(\log (n))^{\log (\log (n))}}=\frac 1{e^{(\log\log n)^2}}\ge \frac 1{e^{\log n}}=\frac1n$$ Isn't it the kind of solution you are looking for?

Comment: @user, actually I am looking for a short solution in which we find a divergent series smaller than $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^{\log(n)}}$ by using only inequalities. I found $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1157}^{\infty}e^{\sqrt n}$ but my solution is not short and I do not like it.

Comment: Your solution is fine, more simply it suffices observe that $$\frac{2^n}{n^{\log n}}=\frac{e^{n\log 2}}{e^{\log^2n}}\ge \frac{e^{\log^2 n}}{e^{\log^2n}}=1$$

Comment: @Angelo Is this way good for what you are looking for?

Comment: @user, I am looking for something similar, but could you explain me how you have proved that $\,n\log2\geqslant \log^2n\,$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\;?$

Comment: It is essentially related to $e^n\ge n^a$ for any $a\in \mathbb R$. There are many proof of that result on the site.

Comment: @user, rather it is related to $e^n\geqslant n^{\log n}$. Please, prove that $n\log2\geqslant\log^2n$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$ by using only inequalities.

Comment: @Angelo We have $n\ge \log^2n \iff \sqrt n\ge \log n \iff e^{\sqrt n}\ge n$. It is essentially the standard inequality I’ve indicated.

Comment: @Angelo Here there are several proof https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468

Comment: It seems that there are not proofs shorter than the one I wrote in a previous comment. Moreover $\,n\log 2\geqslant\log^2n\,$ is not equivalent to $\,n\geqslant\log^2n\,$ or to $\,e^{\sqrt n}\geqslant n$.

Comment: @Angelo As I said from the begining you proof is fine, then you have asked for an alternative and I've given all the example I can. You can also make an official answer here or in the linked question. Regarding the inequality note that  $$e^{\sqrt n}\ge n \implies \sqrt n \ge \log n \implies n\ge \log^2 n$$ the factor $\log 2$ is not relevant since in the same way we can prove that  $e^{\sqrt n}\ge n^2$. Here is another related question where you could add your answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1287704/505767

Comment: @user, thank you very much. I really appreciate all the help you have given me.

Comment: @user, I have already added my answer. Click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4712082/771461).